# Как добавить ссылку "Построить маршрут в Яндекс Картах"

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Я имею гео данные пользователя и гео данные объекта до которого нужно добраться, между ними мне нужно построить маршрут.
Как мне сгенерировать ссылку, перейдя по которой пользователю, либо откроется мобильное приложение яндекс карты, либо если такого приложения нет, то откроется сайт яндекс карты с построенным маршрутом?

Comment: Можно из без схем, тогда гиперссылка и при нали https://yandex.ru/dev/yandex-apps-launch/maps/doc/concepts/yandexmaps-web-docpage/ https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide

Answer (score 2):

Здравствуйте, у мобильного приложения Яндекс.Карты есть url-схема, которая позволяет сгенерировать такую ссылку. В ней доступны параметры `rtext` для определения координат точек маршрута и `rtt` для выбора типа маршрутизации.

Пример:

```
yandexmaps://maps.yandex.ru/?rtext=59.967870,30.242658~59.898495,30.299559&rtt=mt
```

[Документация](https://tech.yandex.ru/yandex-apps-launch/maps/doc/concepts/About-docpage/?from=SO)